# Why is vim.gtk3 looking for libpng12 on Ubuntu 22.4?

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, vim, libpng

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (jammy), `/bin/vim.gtk3`, from the `vim-gtk3` package won't run any more:

```
$ /bin/vim.gtk3 
vim.gtk3: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's correct that `libpng12` isn't included in Ubuntu any more, but surely the Ubuntu 22.04 package wouldn't be requiring it?

Previously I was using a newer version of Vim from a PPA, but that has been removed, and all the `vim-*` packages are those from the official jammy repositories:

```
$ apt-show-versions | grep vim | grep -v :i386
vim:amd64/jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 uptodate
vim-common:all/jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 uptodate
vim-gtk3:amd64/jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 uptodate
vim-gui-common:all/jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 uptodate
vim-runtime:all/jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 uptodate
vim-tiny:amd64/jammy-security 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1 uptodate
```

`vim.basic` still runs fine.

What can I do to make `vim.gtk3` run as intended in Ubuntu 22.04? (I don't want to install an old or unofficial package of `libpng12`, because that can't be how this is supposed to work.)